# C# implementation for identity based encryption(IBE)

Tags: c#-4.0, rsa, public-key-encryption, des, encryption-asymmetric

I am a student and I want to implement Identity based encryption by using c#.

**Example:** I want to encrypt a message by using receivers email address(Public Key) and sender will send this message to receiver. Once receiver receives this encrypted message, he will decry-pt this message by using his private key.

This looks okay theoretically, but I am struggling to do this practically.

**I don't know**

1. how to encrypt a message by using receivers email address
2. how receiver will decry-pt encrypted message?
3. how receiver will get his private key?

**I am expecting help from this platform, as I already spent a lot of time on searching this.**

**What I have tried:**

I tried encryption and decryption by using RSA algorithm, but the problem here is RSA generates his own public and private key pair. And I can not use receivers email address as a public key to encrypt message.

Thank you in advance.
Ashok

Comment: Keys can be exchanges via protocols such as Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange but that begs the question of authentication of the parties. Or they can be exchanged via another channel such as postal mail. And there is PKI (Public Key Infrastructure).

Comment: @zaph Thanks for your reply..Yes we can do that. I am okay with key exchange. But my main goal is to generate keys from email address.. Is it possible?

Comment: I haven't seen a C# implementation for pairing-based cryptography or even identity-based encryption yet. You would need to implement it yourself. It's not that easy. Maybe you can write a wrapper around [PBC](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/). Either way, your question is not answerable with a short and sensible amount of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate secure symmetric keys from an email address, any string for that matter, with a key derivation function such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`).

RSA is asymmetric encryption with separate keys for encryption and decryption, symmetric encryption such as AES uses one key for both encryption and decryption.

Asymmetric encryption  such as RSA has the advantage of two keys where the encryption key can be publicly known. But it is very slow and the data size, the keys are large (2048-bits is a currently secure size) and the data length is limited to the key size, it is generally used to encrypt symmetric keys. There is no control over symmetric key pair creation other than length.  Use asymmetric encryption only when a public/private key pair must be used.

Asymmetric encryption such as AES is fast, has smaller keys with 128-bits common and secure and can handle data of essentially any length.

Comment: thanks for your reply...two different keys public and private are must for me....I need to use asymmetric algorithm...As you mentioned yes, RSA uses two keys, but my basic problem is it generates its own public and private keys..Instead of that I want to use my own public key like Email Id and its respective generated private key..Any private key is accepted..

Comment: Basically what I want is encrypt a text by using receivers email id and receiver will decry-pt this text by using his own private key....private key can be be anything...I don't have problem with private key...

Comment: Why are two keys needed? Why not use the same key for both encryption and decryption. The way public/private key pairs work does not allow any choice of the public key.

Comment: I need two keys because...Sender don't know the receivers private key...and receiver don't want to share his private key to any sender..